# Errors when performing fsck on encrypted partition in recovery mode

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, encryption, fsck

I'm booting in recovery mode
Unmount crypto partition.

`umount /dev/mapper/sda6_crypt` **and i make** `fsck -c /dev/mapper/sda6_crypt`

**fsck output:**

```
fsck.LVM"_member: not found
    fsck: Error 2 while executing fsck.LVM2_member for /dev/mapper/sda6_crypt
```

In crypto volume there are two crypto partitions:

- swap
- home

**I make:**

```
fsck -c /dev/mapper/cifrado-home

fsck.ext2: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext2: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/mapper/cifrado/home
```

**I make:**  `fsck -c /dev/sda6`

```
fsck: fsck.crypto_LUKS: not found
fsck: Error 2 while executing fsck.crypto_LUKS for /dev/sda6
```

Comment: It's useful if you actually ask a question...  :)

Answer (score 2):

**Boot the Ubuntu Desktop CD or go to recovery mode,**

**Install lvm2 and cryptsetup,**

> sudo apt-get install lvm2 cryptsetup

**load the cyrptsetup module :**

> sudo modprobe dm-crypt

**Decrypt your file system,**

> sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/hda5
>   crypt1

**Get the live CD to recognize (activate) your LVM :**

> sudo vgscan --mknodes sudo vgchange
>   -ay

**Run fsck,**

> fsck /dev/mapper/

Answer was found [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=708291).